# What is the best way to switch (slide) images (with fingers) like launcher does?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-image, android-sliding

I have some images and I want to slide through them (just like in launcher or gallery (with fingers)). What is more I need to zoom those images.
I have readen about this and many people recommend using ViewPager. Is that a good idea in my situation?
Implemantation of ViewPager is quite hard, because I need to make an adapter to it. The number of images depends on situation and is not fixed. Is it a problem?
Maybe using ViewFlipper with animations and gestures reader would be better?
What do you think?
Thanks for answers!

Comment: ViewPager was made specifically for this. It's not that hard to get setup, there are plenty of good examples online. And the main upside to using an Adapter is that it makes the View capable of showing an unknown/non-fixed number of data items =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ViewPager. It is the best way to achieve this.

http://code.google.com/p/android-mt-tutorials/source/browse/trunk/SimpleViewPager/?r=10

Will provide a good explanation.

Also you can also use it with http://viewpagerindicator.com/

You can see the effect in action there and download the sample app.

Comment: And if another image is just loaded from Internet (this is how my app will work) can I add it to ViewPager without problems (such as switch to first image or something)?